# Rails mapping attributes to outside source values in most efficient manner

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out the best way to map model attributes to a set of values in an outside service as part of an integration we're doing with them.

For example, let's say our `User` model has an `education_level` attribute with values in our system that we store as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and they equate to:

```
0  8th grade education
1  high school education
2  associate's degree
3  some college
4  bachelor's degree
5  masters or phd degree
```

in their system, they are say 343, 344, 355, 356, 363 and 373. So I want some sort of mapping table like:

```
0  343
1  344
2  355
3  356
4  363
5  373
```

And when I do a `POST` to the external system, we send `344` if the user has 1 stored for `high school education`.

I know I could store this in just a `txt` or `csv` file and do a `File.open` and loop through every line and check to see if the values match. But that doesn't really seem very efficient, especially if there are a lot of values that are possible.

Thoughts on how to accomplish this sort of mapping in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `Hash` in this case:

```
class User
  SERVICE_EDUCATION_LEVELS_MAP = {
    0 => 343,
    1 => 344,
    2 => 355,
    3 => 356,
    4 => 363,
    5 => 373
  }.freeze

  def service_education_level
    SERVICE_EDUCATION_LEVELS_MAP[education_level]
  end
...
end
```

Now you can access this mapping by calling `#service_education_level` on `User` instance.

Comment: Pure genius. Not sure why I didn't think of this.